# Android - Keep Service Running

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I have a system that uses Services to run in background. It work well when the application is opened or "hided". When the user remove it from the recent apps list, I get the log: `I/ActivityManager: Killing 4419:com.cybermickey2077/u0a34 (adj 16): remove task`, or something like, and the Service stops.
What do I need to do to keeps the Service running, even with the application completely closed?

Code:

```
public class TimeCounter extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Workercount = new Worker();
        count.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    class Worker extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                this.verAlarmes();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void verAlarmes() {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());
            Log.e("logmickey", "Now: " + time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For 1 You need a notification with a way for the user to cancel.

Comment: Going forward (to support Android 8+) then services that NEED to stay running must be implemented as a foreground service. A foreground service needs to display a notification in order to keep running.
Read more: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services